# How do I continously change the background color without getting the "too many recursions" error?

Tags: html

How do I continously change the background color?
My following code results in a "too many recursions" error".

```
<html>
<body id = "BGCOLOR" bgcolor = rgb(0,0,0); >
<script>
function ChangeColor(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(Math.random(255),Math.random(255),Math.random(255))";
    setTimeout(ChangeColor(),3000);
}
ChangeColor();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` takes a function, but you're calling the function itself instead. So, you need only pass it `ChangeColor` (without parentheses). Additionally, `Math.random()` returns a floating point number, which will then need to scale up to 255, then converted to an integer to use in `rgb(...)`.

```js
function ChangeColor() {
  var r = parseInt(255 * Math.random());
  var g = parseInt(255 * Math.random());
  var b = parseInt(255 * Math.random());
  var color = "rgb(" + [r, g, b].join(',') + ")";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  setTimeout(ChangeColor, 3000);
}
ChangeColor();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```